# PostGIS and coordinates, determinate if a point is inside a multipolygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have the coordinates: -48.54367281530538 -15.91180231568948

I need to know if these coordinates belong to my multpolygon

```
select boolean st_contains(st_geomfromtext('POINT(-48.54367281530538 -15.91180231568948)',4326), st_geomfromkml(a.geom)) 
from "LIM_Municipio_A" as a
where nome  ilike 'alexânia';
```

My Table:

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) says:

> boolean ST_Contains(geometry **geomA**, geometry **geomB**);
>   Geometry A contains Geometry B if [...]

So you would have to use the polygon first, then the point.

```sql
select st_contains(
    st_geomfromkml(a.geom),
    st_geomfromtext('POINT(-48.54367281530538 -15.91180231568948)',4326)
   ) 
from "LIM_Municipio_A" as a
where nome  ilike 'alexânia';
```